# Does there exist a sequence $x_n$ such that $ \sum x_n >0$ but $ \sum x_n ^3 <0 $ where $ |x_n|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does there exist a sequence $x_n$ such that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n >0$ but $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n ^3 <0 $ where $ |x_n|<1$ for all $n$?

Intuitively I would say no, since cubing preserves the sign of each term and since the first sum is greater than $0$, we can match up each -ve term with a sufficient number of +ve terms such that their sum is +ve. So after cubing each of these 'partial sums' will have the same sign (*i.e.* also +ve) hence the overall sum is also positive.

**Is this correct? Is there a better way of wording the correct argument?**

Comment: I don't think you can just 'match up' each term in one series with one in a different series. In infinite sums, order matters. I believe you need absolute convergence to be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct.

For a counterexample, you can take $x_1=-2/3$, $x_2=1/3$, $x_3=1/3$, $x_4=1/3$ and $x_i=0$ if $i\geq 5$.

You have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n=\frac 13>0$$

but

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {x_n}^3=-\frac 89+\frac 39=-\frac 59<0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take, for instance, $x_n=-3/5$ if $n$ is divisible by $3$ and $2/5$ otherwise. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=\infty$ while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^3=-\infty$.